# Why is a PhD course studied by consultation? And how is the study by consultation done?

Tags: phd, coursework

I have been accepted to do a PhD in Czech Republic. I will be arriving to the University at the end of November 2020.

The supervisor told me to take about three courses and we agreed on which courses I'll take. I then emailed a professor that is responsible of one of the courses and he told me that the course is not organized as a  regular one consisting of a series of lectures. Instead it is supported by a group or individual consultations devoted to specific topics.

So my question is how is the study by consultation done (in detail please)?

Also Why is a PhD course studied by consultation rather than a series of lectures?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In other places such a course might be called "independent study" and involves study with guidance by a professor. Normally there would be readings and some exercises or writings with periodic meetings with the professor. Sometimes the "meetings" are in seminar with a few students.

The usual reasons for such courses is that there is low demand for them and if they are assigned to faculty as part of normal load, then other courses with more demand will be harder to cover. Lecturing to one or two students is a poor use of faculty time, especially for experienced students who should be expected to be able to read and find supplementary resources.

Sometimes such "courses" are also given to be able to offer very esoteric subject teaching. Again, these might be seminars rather than individual "consultations".

For faculty organizational purposes, a faculty member might get "credit" for part of the teaching load but less than that of a full course.